ring A that is right non-singular but is not a left non-singular ring.
I'm trying to find an example of a ring A that is right non-singular  but is not a left non-singular ring.
I considered to find the example on the matrices ring with coefficients in a field but I can not find it.

Welcome to MSE! Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933  before posting questions. I'm not downvoting the question since this is your first question, so you may edit it.

DaRT query returns three pertinent rings.

Thank you for posting your question this time in English.
